# Avoid infinite loop when Java Swing Action Listener class extends another class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I've attached an `ActionListener` to a `JButton` in Swing.

The main class:

```
 class MainClass {

    String foo;
    JButton button = new JButton("cool button");

    public MainClass(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        ...
        JFrame setup here
        ...

        button.addActionListener(new MyBtnListener(frame));
        System.out.println(getFoo());
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }

}
```

The class that implements the `ActionListener` methods:

```
class MyBtnListener extends MainClass implements ActionListener  {

    private JFrame target;

    public MyBtnListener(JFrame target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("button clicked");
        //target.dispose();
    }

}
```

When compiled, the code results in something like this:
`foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo` (an infinite loop). I need the `ActionListener` class to be able to access methods in `MainClass`, while at the same time not repeatedly calling the constructor. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know much about swing but under any condition, `MyBtnListener` should not extend `MainClass`. What you can do is make a nested class inside `MainClass`

Comment: Exactly -- you're mis-using inheritance here, and in fact the liistener should not extend the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is pretty straight forward: what you search for is called a „reference“.

Just add a private field of the type `MainClass` to your listener and initialise it in the constructor:

```
private final JFrame frame;
private final MainClass reference;

public MyBtnListener(final JFrame frame, final MainClass reference)
{
     this.frame = frame;
     this.reference = reference;
}
```

Then you can just invoke the `getFoo` method like this:

```
final String foo = reference.getFoo();
```

It is also very important that the `MyBtnListener` class **doesn't** extend the `MainClass` class.

Answer (score 0):

By having `MyBtnListener` extend `MainClass` and `MainClass` having creating a `MyBtnListener` in its constructor you have created a loop that lasts as long as there is space on the call stack.

Move the `button.addActionListener(new MyBtnListener(frame));` to the constructor of `MyBtnListener` as `button.addActionListener(this);` or don't have `MyBtnListener` extend `MainClass`, just have it implement `ActionListener`.

```
class MainClass {
 String foo;
 JButton button = new JButton("cool button");

 public MainClass(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
    ...
    JFrame setup here
    ...

    button.addActionListener(new MyBtnListener());
    System.out.println(getFoo());
}

public String getFoo() {
    return this.foo;
}
}

class MyBtnListener implements ActionListener  {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("button clicked");
}
```

}